# React sharing components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I have two projects which will need to share components: headers, footers some inputs etc.
Those which will need to be shared are moved into a separate repo. All fine thus far.
In the common repo I currently have set-up webpack which builds and exports them, works like a charm.

Have one question though - could it be possible to export not-compiled react components?

Comment: Exporting your components in a common place in the shared library, adding it then as package.json and importing the components doesn't work?

Comment: @CrazyBarney They contain jsx, so they have to be built, which in turns means that the projects need to include node_modules/common which seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer - I am a maintainer of Bit)

You can use [Bit](https://github.com/teambit/bit) to sync the source of components between different projects. It does not force you to maintain a separate repo for the shared code.
You can compile each component separately or have the consuming project build the imported components.

Comment: I'd love to use bit.dev, but I think it's OP if you just want to have a common shared folder with a few components you don't want to publish, any ideas? I tried to symlink an external folder and ```npm start``` went crazy.

Comment: So in your case you rather have a list of functions somewhere to import to your code? There are many "snippet managers" out there you can use. Bit does it for modules, as it includes all their dependencies, and can also manage test and builds for them.